# onclick for a function in a js file

Tags: web-part, jquery

I'm trying to call a jquery function with the *onclick* attribute of a button:

```
<input type="button" id="palettebutton" value="VALIDER" onclick="getItemsToBeUpdated()"/>
```

I can do this when my script is in the html of the webpart directly, but it doesn't work when I call a js file with the function inside.

How I add the js file :

```
<script src="/sites/DevNum/testjd/SiteReformeTest/js/jquery.js"></script>
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​<script src="/sites/DevNum/testjd/SiteReformeTest/js/palette.js"></script>
```

My js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function getItemsToBeUpdated()

        {
             ...
        }
})
```

Can you tell me how can I do to execute the function on a button click with the script in a js file instead of the html?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you attached your script file using <script> tag in that wepart?

Comment: yes, I have getItemsToBeUpdated undefined when it's in a js file

Comment: I've made an edit

Comment: Remove document.ready() function from js. Use only getItemsToBeUpdate() and try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try below code without `$(document).ready(function(){`

```
$( "#palettebutton" ).click(function() {

---------- Your code will be here ----------  
alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this even without using `$(document).ready(function()`.

Attach JS in your webpart.

```
<script src="/sites/DevNum/testjd/SiteReformeTest/js/palette.js"></script>
```

You just need to remove **`$(document).ready(function(){`** from your code. Write only below function in your JS file.

```
function getItemsToBeUpdated()

        {
             ...
        }
```

And call it in HTML button.

```
<input type="button" id="palettebutton" value="VALIDER" onclick="getItemsToBeUpdated();"/>
```